# SCL and GND connection

Tags: pic, i2c

What happens if SCL of I2C is connected to GND? Does it ruin our controllers clock as well?

I am using PIC24 with three I2Cs. If one I2C's GND and SCL gets short circuited. I stop getting the data of my debug logs.

Comment: 1) include a schematic 2) assuming that you connected the the I2C bus in the correct way then all ICs share the same bus (that's the point of I2C). Then **obviously** if there is no clock (you short it to ground) then the whole bus cannot work. Your question is like: *my car has 4 wheels, when I block one of them (stop the wheel from rotating) the car doesn't work anymore. Is that normal ?*

Answer (score 4):

> What happens if SCL of I2C is connected to GND?

The bus won't work.  This should have been obvious to the point of this being a dumb question.

Data is transferred synchronously with the clock.  When the clock is shorted, there are no clock pulses.  It therefore follows that data can't be transferred.  Again, this should really have been obvious.

Shorting either IIC line to ground does no physical damage.  That is because both lines are passively pulled up and actively pulled down.  Devices only drive low, not high.  There will be no excessive current or any damage.

Answer (score 2):

> What happens if SCL of I2C is connected to GND?

The I2C bus cannot transfer any data during that time. This is similar to a valid, but normally short-duration, condition (see discussion of "clock stretching" below).

> Does it ruin our controllers clock as well?

No. The MCU clock (internal or external) is independent of that I2C signal.

> I am using PIC24 with three I2Cs. If one I2C's GND and SCL gets short circuited. I stop getting the data of my debug logs.

It sounds like perhaps you are a tester, who has been told to simulate some failures including shorting SCL to Gnd and then report whether the device (including debug logging) behaves normally. It would be helpful if you add some context to your question about *why* you are doing that test.

However, even without more info, it's possible to suggest a hypothesis about why you see the reported behaviour.

"Clock stretching" is an optional part of the [I2C specification](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf), where a Slave device can pull SCL low (which is effectively the same as your test), to request the I2C Master to pause I2C bus activity. If the I2C Master code running on your PIC24 is designed to be compatible with I2C Slaves which perform clock stretching, that I2C Master code may simply loop (perhaps *indefinitely*) waiting for the I2C Slave to release (i.e. stop pulling down) the SCL signal.

In that case, the firmware running on the PIC24 doesn't know that the apparent clock stretching is actually being done by *you* shorting SCL to Gnd and could continue for much longer than typical *real* I2C clock stretching. In a very simple "super loop" firmware architecture, with no timeouts etc., that clock stretching condition could cause other parts of the PIC24 firmware (e.g. the debug logging code) to not be executed. That would explain why you "stop getting the data of my debug logs". It all depends on the PIC24 firmware.

**Summary**: It would be *possible* to write PIC24 firmware where holding the I2C SCL signal low *would* cause other parts of the firmware (e.g. including debug logging) to not be executed.

You need to investigate the PIC24 firmware further (or get the firmware's writer to do so, if that person isn't you) to consider whether this hypothesis is indeed the explanation for your observed behaviour.